# Why does my loop "stick" on the first file?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The code below asks the user to select files, then the code "does stuff" to each file selected. The message box portion of the code (which is only there for de-bugging purposes) is correctly displaying each file selected, however the "add sheet" portion of the code is attempting to add the sheet to only 1 of the selected workbooks for every iteration of the loop (so if the user selects 4 files, it attempts to add the "Test" sheet to one of files 4 times).

```
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim wi As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fOpen As Boolean

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
If Not IsArray(myFile) Then
    Exit Sub
Else

    For wi = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
        'If workbook already open, activate. otherwise open it
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(Dir(myFile(wi)))
        fOpen = Not (wb Is Nothing)
        On Error GoTo 0     ' or point to error handler

        If Not fOpen Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile(wi)) 'if file is not open, open it

        End If
        wb.Activate 
        MsgBox myFile(wi)
        wb.Sheets.Add.Name = "TEST"
     next wi
```

Comment: On what line are you having the issue? What's the problem

Comment: It looks like you need to `Set wb = Nothing` before looping back to the next file.

Comment: Domenic - that fixed it, thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!